# Issues in SDL Tridion User Interface 2012

Tags: tridion

I have Installed SDL Tridion User Interface 2012 successfully and able to create a pageType and configure Content Types (from Publication’s properties).
 Now I have below issues/concerns -

1. As per my understanding whenever a new page will be created using this page type, all the metadata, components etc. should be cloned.
   But I am not getting any option to select a page type during page creation.
2. Is it possible to create multiple content types per publication and how I can allow a Content Type on a specified Page Type?

Comment: This is all covered in the docs...

Comment: Could you please give me the name of doc ? may be I missed this one somehow

Comment: User interface update for SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 Installation Manual

Comment: I've had browser cache issues when trying to use page or content types right after creating them. Restarting the browser "fixed" it.

Comment: We can make pages from the UI 2012 (Experience Manager) by first having a page in the CME that has "use as page type" checkbox selected.

Answer (score 9):

Content Types are only used in SiteEdit -- and yes, you can create multiple per Publication. You configure this on the Dashboard tab.

For more information, have a look at the [documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/UIU4SDLT2011SP1/concept_F774D9E710B74D6B9BC16EDB7649397B) on LiveContent.